# CSS menu drops down when it isnt hovered over

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

I am making a menu in css and I want it to dropdown when I hover over a certain block, but right now it is starting off dropped down when I open the web page. Here is my code

```
#header_menu.li: ul.dropdown{
display: none;
}

#header_menu.li: ul.dropdown hover {
    display: block;
    position absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
    bottom: 60px;
    /* makes drop up start at top of footer */
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 0px;
    /* top left corner, top right corner, bottom right corner, bottom left corner */
}
```

EDIT is still isnt working here is my html

```
   <li> <a href = "#"> Account </a> 
            <ul class = "dropdown">

            <li><a href = "#"> Standings</li>

            <li><a href = "#"> Playoff Picture</li>

            <li><a href = "#"> Group Chat</li>

            <li><a href = "#"> Schedule</li>

            </ul>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selectors are incorrect

```css
#header_menu.li: ul.dropdown
```

should be

```css
#header_menu.li ul.dropdown
```

and

```css
#header_menu.li: ul.dropdown hover
```

should be

```css
#header_menu.li:hover ul.dropdown
```

that is if `li` is a class and not an `<li>` tag

---

Edit
And `li` is a tag so

```css
#header_menu li ul.dropdown{
    display: none;
}

#header_menu li:hover ul.dropdown{
    display: block;
    position absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
    bottom: 60px;
    /* makes drop up start at top of footer */
    border: 1px solid #111111;
    border-bottom: none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 7px 0px 0px 0px;
    /* top left corner, top right corner, bottom right corner, bottom left corner */
}
```

Comment: @user2109242 well lets see the html.

Comment: @user2109242 the part after the line

Comment: @user2109242 look again really really closely.

Comment: @user2109242 those were the selectors see edit again (under the line)